# c# creating object in specific memory address

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

Is it possible in C# (in a unsafe Codecontext ) to create an Object at a specific memory address?

My Code:

```
object _apiId = new ApiId();
var apiID = (ApiId)_apiId;
ApiId* pointer = &apiID;
Debug.Write(new Intptr(pointer));
```

Comment: The Marshall.StructureToPtr method may help you. If you explain a little better what you want to achieve I could give you a better hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

p/invoke the method: memcpy from msvrct.dll:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern IntPtr memcpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);
```

you need the size of your object you want to copy:

```
var size = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
```

you need to pin it:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

finally call the method memcpy:

```
 var _adress = NativeMethods.memcpy(new IntPtr(1115911111), handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), new UIntPtr(size));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because memory address is meaningless when GC can move objects and pointers becomes invalid. This is why a keyword `reference` is used here instead of `pointer`

Comment: Personally, I don't find the explanation satisfatory. In other situations, GC can be "taken out of the equation" (e.g., `GCHandleType.Pinned`), so it wouldn't surprise me if something similar could be done in this situation.

Comment: Arrays and so on can be pinned, but you haven't full C++ control over unsafe code. For example, code like `MyStruct x = *(MyStruct*)((void*)0xDEADBEEF)` are not allowed even in unsafe C#

Comment: I know, "unsafe" is limited in C#, but I don't think "memory address is meaningless when GC can move objects and pointers becomes invalid" is the reason why.